I trying to make a screen into this shape is there anyone that can help?
what's up guys, im attempting to create a very unique shape to blender, it has a very organic structure to it and was just asking for tips on how to recreate this shape

Like I mentioned I want to make this Into a screen to utilize on my project, anyone have any idea of how to who about it

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
